# Error while linking libvorbisfile.dylib into Mac application

Tags: oggvorbis, symbol-not-found

I'm working on a program that loads sounds from Ogg Vorbis files, but whatever I do, the XCode project just doesn't seem to want to link libvorbisfile.a into my program. I keep getting linking errors:

```
"_ov_read", referenced from:
    GSound::GSound(GWorld*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)in GSound.o
    GSound::GSound(GWorld*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)in GSound.o
"_ov_clear", referenced from:
    GSound::GSound(GWorld*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)in GSound.o
    GSound::GSound(GWorld*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)in GSound.o
"_ov_info", referenced from:
    GSound::GSound(GWorld*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)in GSound.o
    GSound::GSound(GWorld*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)in GSound.o
"_ov_open", referenced from:
    GSound::GSound(GWorld*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)in GSound.o
    GSound::GSound(GWorld*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)in GSound.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
```

Comment: Hi mate, i am developing an app that needs the ogg vorbis framework to play ogg, can you point me in the right direction to succesfully link these libraries, thanks in advance

Comment: It's been a while since I was working on this, but if I recall correctly you have to download the source distribution then compile it as a framework instead of as a static or shared library. Then you can just drag it into Xcode like any other framework if you're on a Mac. On Linux, just install it with your favorite package manager and -lvorbisfile -logg -lvorbis. Can't help with Windows though, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. I had to compile Vorbis as a framework.